# SQL Server 2008 - Delete repeating characters preceded by a number

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, replace, substring

I have a string that may or may not contain a repeating letter `z`. The repeating `z's` will always be preceded by a number. It is being used as a filler. The issue I'm having is that the string may contain legitimate letter `z's` that are not preceded by a number so I can't do a simple replace all `z's` with `''`.

Here is a sample:

```
declare @criteria varchar(max)
set @criteria = ' Process Level = 31129     Process Level = 32045zzzz   Leader = Gail     Zimmerman  Process Level >= 21 AND Process Level <= 25zzzzzzz  Leader = John Schwartz   '
```

The result should be:

```
  Process Level = 31129     Process Level = 32045   Leader = Gail Zimmerman  Process Level >= 21 AND Process Level <= 25  Leader = John Schwartz
```

Comment: I'm not a regex guru and it'd be painfully slow for me to try and answer in full when you can get better answers, but something along the lines of `[[number]][z]` to look for these sections may be required - not sure what RDBMS you're using to give you more specific syntax but regex in your specific RDBMS is probably a good starting point research wise for you

Comment: Is the number of "columns" fixed? How many columns are there?

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately regex is not an available command. The columns are not fixed. the data can be null or up to thousands of characters. It's an audit log and the field is ntext.

Answer (score 0):

Silly question; why in the WORLD would you use a standard character as a filler??

Anyway...  This is kind of convoluted but you can use the REVERSE function to flip the string backwards, trim off the now LEADING Z's (as opposed to TRAILING) by using the LEFT function, and then REVERSE the string again.

Complete "aircode" (geared more towards VBA, because that's my strength), but here's the idea:

```
X = REVERSE(ProcessLevel)

For Z = 1 to Len(X)
  If Left(X) = "Z" then
    X = Right(X, Len(X) -Z)
  Else
    X = Reverse(X)
  EndIf
Next Z

ProcessLevel = X
```

Comment: I asked the same question. Unfortunately, I have no control, I only query against it. Thank you for replying, this sounds interesting.

Answer (score 0):

This is for T-SQL, there may be syntax variations in other RDBMSs.

Disclaimer: this is slow and really not very pretty, but as full regex isn't part of SQL, there's not a lot you can do if you're constrained to doing this within the language.

```
while @criteria like '%[0-9]Z%'
begin
select @criteria = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@criteria, '1z','1'), '2z', '2'), '3z','3'),'4z','4'),'5z','5'),'6z','6'),'7z','7'),'8z','8'),'9z','9'),'0z','0')
end

select @criteria
```

It looks like the string is combined from a selection of other fields. It would be a lot simpler to work with them if possible.

Comment: Yes it is a combination of other fields, unfortunately, I have to query against the log for the data (point in time), so I am limited to what the log entails. And the log was not setup to provide the fields separately, but instead to list the actions in a long (sometimes very long) single field. This code would work, and I'm doing something similar already for another part of the query, and I was hoping to avoid the multitude of replace statments, but at least I know this will work with what you;ve written, thank you.